# Are there any reasons to not use 50 frames per second?

Tags: video-recording

When you set a GoPro to mitigating flickering problems in Europe, where AC comes at 50Hz, instead of 30 and 60FPS, you get 25 and 50FPS as the options. I'm recording videos to upload to YouTube. Normally I would go for 30 or 60FPS.

Are there any reasons to not record at 50FPS?

I haven't checked whether I get flickering at 60FPS, but I would have to check with each light I'm using. It might not be visible until I playback on a big screen and I don't know when I'm going to encounter a flickering light ruining some footage.

Update: the resulting video will be uploaded to YouTube and snippets will be uploaded to Instagram, TikTok, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends what frame rate you need to deliver your final project at.

If you're delivering at 30 or 60 fps, then your 50 fps source material will have to drop or create frames in order to deliver at 30 or 60.

This is visible, especially on long smooth pans for example.

50 fps is useful for delivering for european / UK broadcast which is often at 25 fps - when it's a multiple of your original source material, the dropping of every other frame isn't jarring - there won't be any suddenly noticeable jumps, unlike trying to divide 50 into 30.

You might decide that a flickering light is more annoying than the frame rate conversion. Or you can sometimes get away with running footage at a slower or faster rate instead of doing frame rate conversion (but this often looks odd if there are humans moving or speaking in the shot).

Comment: It's for uploading to YouTube, so any frame rate is pretty much ok, as far as I know.